# How to differentiate between formal parameter, local variable and data member in context of same class

Tags: java

```
//Test.java

class Demo
{
        int a;//data member

    void ex(int a)//formal parameter
    {
            int a = 100;//local variable
            this.a = a;// here I am differentiating data member and formal 
                       // parameter by using this keyword
            System.out.println("Val of a = "+a);
    }
}//Demo-------------->BLC

class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Demo d = new Demo();
             d.ex(10);
    }
}//Test------------->ELC
```

I can differentiate between data member (`int a`) and formal parameter (`int a`) by using implicit reference variable (`this`). My question is, how can I differentiate between data member (`int a`), formal parameter (`int a`) and local variable (`int a`) in same class?

Comment: You can't or rather couldn't. Which is why the code above will not compile and give you the error: Duplicate local variable a

Comment: I agree what you said because I compiled but it shows error. But when I put int b = 100 instead of int a = 100 then it compiled successfully. Then there should be some way na to differentiate.

Comment: Function input args are already declared local in the function's scope. You thus can't _declare_ another local variable `a` in a function having an input argument `a`. You can _rewrite_ the local variable's value (`a = 100;`), but you can't redeclare it. What you are doing is efficiently the same as trying to write `int a = 10; int a = 11;`.

Comment: @Vaibhavkumar: That's how you differentiate: Different names. There's no *other* way to differentiate, but that's how you do it. (In Java, C, C# JavaScript, Basic, and nearly every other programming language I've used. Typically there is no notational difference between a parameter and a local.)

Answer (score -1):

You can't have a formal parameter and a local variable with the same name, it's a compilation error:

> variable `a` is already defined in method `ex(int)`

So the issue of how to differentiate them doesn't come up. Just give them different (ideally meaningful) names.

As you've noted, the issue of an instance variable (data member) vs. a formal parameter/local variable is handled via `this.`

Comment: Side note: Some argue you should always use `this.` on instance members even if there isn't a naming conflict, so it's clear you intend to be using an instance member (and will get a compilation error if you don't have one with the relevant name). Others argue it clutters things up. You and your team should come to an agreed position on that and then apply it consistently (tools can help).

Answer (score -1):

This code should make it clear:

```
public class Test {

    private int b = 5; // Instance variable.
    private int c = 7; // Instance variable.
    private static int d = 7; // Static variable.
    private static int e = 9; // Static variable.

    public void aMethod(int a) { // a = formal parameter.

        // Compile error. There is already a variable named "a" here, it is the parameter.
        int a = 5;

        int b = 5; // Local variable. Shadows the instance variable.

        b = 6; // Assigns to local variable.
        this.b = 6; // Assigns to instance variable.
        c = 8; // Assigns to instance variable.
        d = 9; // Assigns to static variable.
        int e = 10; // Local variable;
        e = 11; // Assigns to local variable.
        Test.e = 12; // Assigns to static variable.
    }
}
```

So, there are two levels of scope here, local scope and object/class scope. No two variables with the same name can be declared in the same scope. The variable which the compiler will reference is the one found in the deepest scope where it can be found.

Another more complicated example:

```
public class Test2 {

    private int a = 5; // Instance variable.

    public void aMethod(int a) { // a = formal parameter.

        class LocalClass {
            private int a;

            public void bMethod() {
                int a = 5; // Local to bMethod;
                this.a = 6; // Instance of LocalClass.
                Test2.this.a = 7; // Instance of Test2.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here there are four nested scopes (`Test` class, `aMethod` body, `LocalClass` class and `bMethod` body). Each variable will be located in the deepest scope where it would be found. Shadowed variables can be referenced (sometimes) by using of `this` or a classname reference (as in `Test.e`). If the `this` itself is shadowed, you can use the `ClassName.this` syntax.

Shadowing is considered a bad practice since it gives the same names to different things creating confusion and there are few to no reasons to do this (although it is tolerated in the case of setter parameters shadowing a field on the same class). So please, avoid doing that.